# testcafe: better error messages for native dialogs

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm testing an app that should never show a native dialog, so if one ever pops up, it should be in error. By default, testcafe does fail if you don't have a handler. That's the behavior I want. But the thing is, It doesn't tell you what the dialog said in the testcafe error message. How do I make native dialogs fail, but still report the alert text?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best thing I figured out:

```
  await t.setNativeDialogHandler((type, text) => {
    throw new Error(text);
  });
```

This isn't perfect: If the error is on the fixture page, it'll error before this code is run. You'll end up getting the unhelpful error message you get when you don't have a native dialogue handler.